# RequestHeader apache httpd not being set

Tags: apache, rhel, request-headers

I am trying to set the RequestHeader in a apache httpd environment.
I created a very simple html page and simple setup to verify but whatever I do it does not create a request header. I verified if mod_headers is installed and setting a normal (response) header workes just fine.
Even using a .htaccess file to set the RequestHeader it is not working.
We are using the following setup:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
- Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)

Virtualhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName localhost
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_81
        TransferLog /var/log/httpd/access_81
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html81
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml
        Header add test "test"
        RequestHeader add test "test"
</VirtualHost>
```

In the image is visible that the Header is set but not the RequestHeader
[header example in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4mjN.png)
Sadly nothing works to get the header.
Anyone knows what to do to get the RequestHeader working on apache?

Comment: You can't see that request header in Firefox console, it is added to the request only once the request reaches Apache (so Firefox is completely unaware of it)

Comment: That's too bad. We are running a jira which works fines in chrome but not in InternetEXplorer or Firefox. They need to be visible to the browser as well. Do you know another way to set request headers visible to the browser(without editing the code, because we can't)?

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand what you are trying to achieve (or even what your problem is)

Comment: Hmm already solved the problem. It was working correctly but a reverse proxy was causing issues.